# glDrawTransformFeedback not write to buffer

Tags: opengl, transform-feedback

I try to use transform features to create a particle system, so there are 2 tranform buffer and 2 array buffer, use ping-pong to switch.

And my shader is simple, just keep add source position.

```
gs_Position = vs_Position[0] + vec3(1, 0, 1);
```

If use glDrawTransformFeedback(), 2 buffer will keep original data, not change.But if I switch to glDrawArrays(), then ping-pong works, position value keep increase.

Initial code

```
shader.setupShaderFromFile(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "feedback.vert");
shader.setupShaderFromFile(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, "feedback.geom");
const GLchar* feedbackVaryings[] = { "gs_Position", "gs_Velocity" };
glTransformFeedbackVaryings(shader.getProgram(), 2, feedbackVaryings, GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);
shader.linkProgram();

glGenTransformFeedbacks(2, tfo);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

Particle* p = new Particle[2];
p[0].position = glm::vec3(1, 2, 3);
p[1].position = glm::vec3(2, 3, 4);

glGenBuffers(2, bfo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bfo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Particle)*2, p, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tfo[0]);
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, bfo[0]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bfo[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Particle)*2, nullptr, GL_STATIC_READ);

glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tfo[1]);
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, bfo[1]);
```

perform transform

```
int from = pid;
int to = (pid + 1) % 2;

glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tfo[to]);
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, bfo[to]);

shader.begin();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bfo[from]);
{
    GLint inputAttrib = shader.getAttributeLocation("a_Position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(inputAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(inputAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Particle), (void*)offsetof(Particle, position));
}
{
    GLint inputAttrib = shader.getAttributeLocation("a_Velocity");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(inputAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(inputAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Particle), (void*)offsetof(Particle, velocity));
}

glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_POINTS);
//glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 2);
glDrawTransformFeedback(GL_POINTS, tfo[from]);
glEndTransformFeedback();

shader.end();

glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, 0);
```

Comment: "*I try to use transform features to create a particle system*" Please do not use transform feedback for particle systems, unless you cannot use compute shaders.

Comment: Transform feedback has a easier way to emit and destory particle @NicolBolas